# Facebook GraphAPI search

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to perform a search based on a hashtag on the Facebook GraphAPI v2.3?

I saw on their documentation that there might be a node for this thing, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The hashtag node is only to be used in Facebook's Trending APIs (You will not be able to access the trending API)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/hashtag

So, no, there is no way to the a Graph API search with hashtags.